# How to repeat an action in Python

Tags: python

I want to repeat an action for n times. I've tried "if" but it does not work.

```
If actiontimes == n:
    Print text*n
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: For one thing, that's not Python; case matters.

Comment: Your code is invalid Python, but you can create a function and count how many times you run the function.

Comment: [**The `range()` Function**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) and [**`for` Statements**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) are shown in the first chapters of the tutorial. How could you miss that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write:

```
for x in range(times):
    #action to repeat
```

Comment: @Ahhaha please don't comment 'thanks'. Instead, accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to if it solved your problem.